# How to install Light Fixtures - no ground in the ceiling box

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I am trying to install a lighting fixture that I bought from Ikea.  The ceiling box has one black, one white, one blue, and one yellow lines (as in the photo below).  But, I cannot find a ground line in the box.   Can anyone explain how I can connect the ground line in the lighting fixture?  Also, I would like to use a switch to turn on and off the lighting, but I'm not sure which hot wire I should use. I guess it may be blue or yellow.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know, get an electrician. Your life and property are at stake.

I could make some educated guesses here but if you followed them, had a problem, and I found out about it, I'd feel bad.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a bare ground wire up in the box somewhere. Connect the green wire to that.
The lamp black goes to yellow.
The lamp white goes to white.
The little double white goes to your bulb.
The black and the blue in the yellow wire nuts are just pass throughs not used for the light.

Comment: You cannot be entirely sure of the function of any of those wires without testing.

Comment: Sorry, except for the ground. bare or green pretty much always means ground (in the US)